# Выделение "по крайней мере"

Tags: пунктуация

**Я весь промок! Ну что ж, по крайней мере, я одел непромокаемую обувь.**
*/сомневаюсь в запятой перед я, но аргументировать затрудняюсь.*

Comment: В смысле: "я одел по крайней мере обувь"

Comment: надел: надел одежду - одел Надежду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По крайней мере - это вводные слова, запятые нужны, а вместо слова "одел" должно быть "надел"